# How to set proxy in SentenceTransformers?

Tags: python, proxy, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to send proxy address to [sentence transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) but am not able to figure out the right way.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-distilroberta-base-v1')
```

Usually, this piece will download the model, but for a system with proxy it is not working. Based on the [Huggingface Transformer Configuration](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/configuration.html?highlight=proxy), I found that I have to use the proxy using, `proxies (Dict[str, str], optional)` – A dictionary of proxy servers to use by protocol or endpoint, e.g., `{'http': 'foo.bar:3128', 'http://hostname': 'foo.bar:4012'}`.

Let's say my proxy is "http://myproxy.mydomain.com:1123".  How do I use the proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out how to download it behind the proxy.

1. Download your favorite models from the [link](https://public.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reimers/sentence-transformers/v0.2/) using Wget. Set proxy to python using `os.environ['http_proxy']` or `https`.
2. Unzip the files to the following location: `.cache\torch\sentence_transformers\` with a prefix `sbert.net_models_`
3. Now your models are good to use with `embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-distilroberta-base-v1')`.

Comment: The same problem happens to me. I wish you could clarify this further. Is it like this? 
``allenai_spector= wget("url")``
``model=SentenceTransformer(allenai_spector)``
It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this code snippet to go through proxies:

```py
    os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://host_1:port_1'
    os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'https://host_2:port_2'
    model = SentenceTransformer('nq-distilbert-base-v1')
```